# Is Eloquera or db4o better suited for my web application?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, db4o, eloquera

I'm considering using an object oriented database in Visual Studio .NET for my web application, which is basically a web store.

Which should I consider, [Eloquera](http://eloquera.com/eloquera-db) or [db4o](http://db4o.com/)? Can I have some fresh perspective?
[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964346/real-world-experience-of-db4o-and-or-eloquera-database) was asked like 10 months ago - please also mention changes since then.

The features that I consider important are:

1. Ease of integration into web application project.
2. Ease of querying using LINQ.
3. Ease of deployment upon release in IIS server.
4. Multi user support.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Real World Experience of db4o and/or Eloquera Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964346/real-world-experience-of-db4o-and-or-eloquera-database)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like db4o could be a fit for your needs, but that depends on two factors:

1. If you're going to host your web store on a hosting provider db4o won't work in a limited trust environment
2. Depending on the number of simultaneous users, db4o could be a fit or not. As a rule of thumb I would say that if you're talking about more than 50 users hitting the db at the same time, then you should look at other options (one example: [Versant Object Database](http://www.versant.com/versant-database-engine.shtml)).

*Disclosure:* I work for Versant and db4o.

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be [RavenDb](http://ravendb.net) -- it is more of a document database than an object database but it satisfies your requirements by and large:

- Easy Integration: insanely easy; use nuget
- Easy Linq: linq is the query platform
- Easy for IIS: pretty much set up an application pointed there and you are done
- Multi-User: yup.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest Eloquera. All the pros of db4o (and more), less some cons...

[Real World Experience of db4o and/or Eloquera Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964346/real-world-experience-of-db4o-and-or-eloquera-database/3217209#3217209)

Comment: Did you actually read the license of Eloquera? The first 3 bullet points under #1 say that you are not allowed to:  "• disclose the results of any benchmark tests of the software to any third party without Eloquera’s prior written approval;
• work around any technical limitations in the software;
• reverse engineer, decompile or disassemble the software, except and only to the extent that applicable law expressly permits, despite this limitation;". Second bullet point means you can't workaround bugs, and the 3rd means you can't debug into the code to see why it's not working.

Comment: Yes, Eloquera isn't open source, but considering its development is a lot more active, possible bugs are bound to be corrected faster than you could debug and correct a bug in db4o... I don't think ChrisF wants to develop a ODB, but rather USE it.

Answer (score 2):

Eloquera is multihreaded, in opposite to db4o. So, if you expect more that a single visitor to your website, Eloquera is an obvious winner here.

Moreover, Eloquera provides the object-oriented and document-oriented APIs, which can be used together.